# Trouble Loading Nested Values from application.yaml in Logback for Kafka Appender Configuration

Tags: spring-boot, logging, apache-kafka, logback, appender

I'm currently working with the latest version of Logback (1.4.14) in my microservice application and facing an issue with configuring a Kafka appender. My goal is to avoid hardcoding values for the Kafka appender configuration, especially for different environments like development, pre-production, and production.

In my `application.yaml` file, I have the Kafka configuration nested under `kafka.consumer.topic` like this:

```yaml
kafka:
  consumer:
    topic: example.topic
```

I'm trying to load these nested values into my Logback configuration `logback.xml` file using the `${kafka.consumer.topic}` syntax, but I'm encountering an issue where the `topic` value remains undefined.

Here's how I'm attempting to load the value in `logback.xml`:

```xml
<topic>${kafka.consumer.topic}</topic>
```

However, this approach doesn't seem to be working as expected, and the `topic` value remains undefined.

I've also tried using the `<property resource="">` and `<variable>` tags in Logback's configuration, but I'm facing the same issue.

```xml
<property resource="application.yaml" />
<variable scope="context" file="application.yaml" />
```

Unfortunately, using `application.properties` instead of `application.yaml` is not an option due to company practices.
PS logback version is 1.4.14, java 17, spring boot 3.1.5
Can someone please provide guidance on how to correctly load nested values from `application.yaml` into Logback's configuration?

Thank you!